# how to match these records belonging to 2 different tables

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have 2 tables (2008 mssql database), lets say x.dbo  and y.dbo

x.dbo has a field name called "customer name" and y.dbo has a field name called "customers".. what I want is filtering the customers that match all *and* that partially match..(2 of the conditions together)

here is my query:
Select    x.customername AS Alıcı, y.customers FROM y cross JOIN  x
Where (x.Alıcı LIKE '%' + customers + '%')

the above query gives some of the matching records but not all of them..

To give an example, the query finds this record successfully:

```
CUSTOMER NAME   CUSTOMERS
BARKIN KULA     barkın kula
```

but does not give this one:

```
CUSTOMER NAME   CUSTOMERS
KÜBRA ÇALIŞKAN  Kybele Global Kübra Çalışkan
```

although both fields contains "kübra çalışkan"..

but on the other hand;
it finds this one which is very similar with the "kübra çalışkan" example above:

```
CUSTOMER NAME                               CUSTOMERS
KVK TEKNOLOJİ ÜRÜNLERİ VE TİC.A.Ş.-MERKEZ   kvk teknoloji ürünleri
```

so I am not sure why my query works ok for some of the records and does not work ok for the others.

Comment: `x.dbo` is not a table at all, mybe you mean `MyDatabase.dbo.x`, and tables has columns not fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the LIKE-mathing both ways:

```
WHERE x.customername LIKE '%' + y.customers    + '%'
OR    y.customers    LIKE '%' + x.customername + '%'
```

This assumes that your collation is set to a "CI"-variant (Case Insensitive). If you are using a "CS"-variant (Case Sensitive) then you can add `UPPER(...)` or `LOWER(...)` on all column names in the query, or specify `COLLATE` with a CI-variant such as in this example:

```
WHERE x.customername LIKE '%' + y.customers    + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
OR    y.customers    LIKE '%' + x.customername + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: this I tried also and does not work either. but I forgot to mention that these 2 tables are joined like this:
SELECT    X.customername AS Alıcı, y.customers
FROM            y cross JOIN  x
where (x.customername LIKE '%' + y.customers + '%')

Comment: @MelihCavli That is a bit unclear to me, please expand on it and at the same time [put it in the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50926897/edit) so other people don't have to hunt for useful details all over the place.

Comment: when I reverse it  (y.customers    LIKE '%' + x.customername + '%')  it finds 0 records. and if reverse it with a "=" statement then it finds some records..
fe:    y.customers   =  x.customername  (finds some records)

Comment: tried this and did not work:
where x.customername LIKE '%' + y.customers    + '%' COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS OR    y.customers    LIKE '%' + x.customername + '%'  COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE X(
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(45)
    );

CREATE TABLE Y(
    Customers NVARCHAR(45)
    );

INSERT INTO X VALUES
(N'BARKIN KULA'),
(N'KÜBRA ÇALIŞKAN');

INSERT INTO Y VALUES
(N'barkın kula'),
(N'Kybele Global Kübra Çalışkan');

SELECT *
FROM X JOIN Y ON
UPPER(X.CustomerName) LIKE '%' + UPPER(Y.Customers)    + '%'
OR    UPPER(Y.Customers)    LIKE '%' + UPPER(X.CustomerName) + '%';
```

Results:

```
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
|    |  CustomerName  |          Customers           |
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | BARKIN KULA    | barkın kula                  |
|  2 | KÜBRA ÇALIŞKAN | Kybele Global Kübra Çalışkan |
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
```

Which mean that you have a `Case sensitive collation`, something like `Latin1_General_CS_AS` (where the `CS` = `Case sensitive`), you may also consider to change it.

You can run the query below to see the collation of your database:

```
SELECT name, collation_name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'YourDatabaseName';
```

To change the collation of your database, just run the query:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
   COLLATE Collation;
```

To see the  available collations, and pick the right one:

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations();
```

Comment: Hi Sami, your code worked.. but I need to make the same thing work on my tables with my query..where do you think the problem is with my query?

Comment: @MelihCavli Did you add the `UPPER()` function to your query? same as mine and see the results?

Comment: thx for your help...
my database has this collation name:Turkish_CI_AS
but I don't want to change the collation because if I change it then other queries that work now might get broken, right?

Comment: yes I added the UPPER() to my query and still nothing has changed

Comment: It is working now..the trick is with the filed type; I converted nchar to nvarchar and it worked:)
thx for all the help